# How can I correctly indicate a math notation inside parentheses in text?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I want to indicate a mathematical notation inside parentheses to define meaning like `job (j)`.

Here, I observe that paranthesis inside and outside of dollar sign differs from each other. I get lost, whether should I keep paranthesis inside the dollar sign or not.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\phantom{}\\
Structure that contains the job ($j$). \\
Structure that contains the job (\,$j$\,). \\
Structure that contains the job $(j)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

First one, paranthesis slightly touches to j. Third one has a less bolder parenthesis than the first one, which differ from normal used paranthesis.

What is a correct way to indicate a math notation inside paranthesis in inline text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is typography not mathematical semantics I would let the semantics guide me. Here the () are definitely part of the sentence structure so I'd keep them outside the `$` so `($j$)`. I might, if it concerned me, do `($\,j$)` but I probably wouldn't and I'd certainly not add space after the j.